# Detect a colored ball regardless of the light

Tags: opencv, video-tracking

I'm trying to detect an orange ball regardless of the lighting conditions. I wanted to point out that in my algorithm I convert an RGB image to HSV (which should be independent of the brightness) but not in optimum conditions I can not find the ball.

Update: these are two image the with different light condition.

[image]

[image]

If I find the ball in the first image I can not find it in the second image and vice versa.

Update: this is the result using HougCircle

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,100,param1=75,param2=16,minRadius=100,maxRadius=1000)
```

[image]
However i need to know what is the color of the ball. Is there a method to find the color of the circle found with with HoughCircles

Comment: And what is your problem? More to the point, what is your question?

Comment: What's the background? How big is the ball in the image? How fast does it move? Are there other moving objects? Can you post some images? What code have you got so far?

Comment: Can you show sample images on optimal and not optimal  conditions?

Comment: The background is a wall whose color is different from the ball. There aren't others objects that can move. The ball's size into the image can be vary variable (it can be near or away the camera). I'll post the image as soon as possible. However i want to precise that changing manually the HSV range (in opencv method cv2.inRange(...)) I can every times find the ball in the image. I'd like to know if there is same algorithm to change it automatically.

Comment: you should try to normalize the image (e.g. white balance) to remove ambient light influence?!?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to your problem could be to look for circles using the hough transform. This approach is based on the observation that there is clear border of the ball against the background.

Comment: I've tried but when the ball is away from the camera HoughCircles gave bad  output: it not finds the ball.